# Laravel 5 Auth - What exactly are it's methods?

Tags: php, laravel

I've just picked up laravel, so a total novice at this.

I'm using the native Authorisation services.

in the view app.blade.php is a line `@if (Auth::guest())`

If I go searching though `...\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth` there's heaps of methods all over the place....

Is there any cheat sheet / summary? The documentation online at laravel doesn't seem to have any.

Comment: Google is your friend...

Comment: have you gone through [this link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication)?

Comment: What you exactly wants? `...\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth...` you can see here all login and register method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [LINK1](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/15)
and here watch last four videos [LINK2](https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5-1)
You will get full idea :)

Comment: Thanks... I had heard of laracasts... but never realised just how useful it is!

Comment: if you buy those tutorial for one month 9$ you can expert on **Laravel**